# advanced and unusual function declaration in C

Tags: c, function, declaration

I asked this question because I didn't even understand how to look for it in the internet. So this is the line of code :

```
FUNC(input_1, input_2) function_name(void)
{
        /*
         * here is my code, no return is written at the end 
         */

}
```

can anyone please explain to me what is this form of declaration  or casting.

Comment: I don't know, and nobody else will know either. You have to search *your own source tree* not the Internet.

Comment: Most likely a macro of some sort. Nothing standard so it's impossible to answer your question without more information.

Comment: If this compiles, it's certainly some macro… but I can't imagine what kind of macro would allow it to become something useful.

Comment: @Joachim :  All what i asked is what is this form of declaration, not what FUNC itself does. There were no return in the function but I see some kind of "casting" and there was no need for down voting.

Comment: @mah: thanks for your comment. Yes it compiles without error, so I will need to now more about macros. As I said I am not asking for what "FUNC" itself does but rather what is this form of declaration. That is all people, no need for down voting.

Comment: Find the definition of `FUNC`.  It really shouldn't be hard, with ctags or Visual Studio, or whatever environment you're using.  Most compilers have a switch to show you the output of the PreProcessor, prior to compilation.

Comment: I didn't down-vote, but I'm thinking about closing as unclear. Since we don't know what `FUNC` is, or what it does, there is simply no way of answering this question. It's *probably* a preprocessor macro that expands to `void`, but that's all anyone can say for now.

Comment: Joachim and Jite have very kindly answered your question in their comments. It is not any "form of declaration or casting". As Jite says `FUNC` is probably a macro which will be replaced with something else by the preprocessor. So as Joachim says you need to find out what the macro expands to, and since code can define macros, and this is not a standard macro, you have to search your own source code.

Comment: You keep using the term "form of declaration", and we keep telling you, ***"This is not a valid C declaration of any kind"***.  Its a macro; you must find the macro definition.

Comment: However since you don't even know what a macro is  (and are being rude to people who are trying to help) I am downvoting and close-voting as "failed to demonstrate minimal understanding".

Comment: Thanks everyone for answering, I am still a beginner with C and I m trying hard to understand. As i can see, it deals with macros, so I will check the code source again and post an answer if I get it, thanks again :)

Comment: @Ben: Don't misunderstanding me please, but I got shocked how some people reacted, that is all. I am trying my best, I will take your comment into my consideration and make better states next time :)

Comment: @Abelenky: I got your idea, please easy on me ;) I am trying to figure it out. Thanks for replying !

Comment: @Heisenberg I also didn't downvote, yet you address that in your reply to me. People who feel the it appropriate to downvote will do so; speaking out against it won't help your cause, and suggestions that specific people downvoted (particularly when they did not) certainly won't help your cause -- be it on stack overflow, or a reasonable analogy elsewhere in life.

Answer (score 1):

You should check your source code, probably `FUNC` is a macro. If you are not sure were to look for the macro you can tell your compiler to stop after the preprocessor phase (MSVC: compiler switch `/EP` or `/P`, gcc: compiler switch `-E`) and then take a look what the compiler sees after the preprocessor has expanded all macros.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are under a *nix-based system, executing:

```
   find . -regex ".*\.\([chCH]\|cc\|CC\)" | xargs grep -n --color FUNC
```

With possibly further doing

```
    | grep define -n --color
```

at the end of the first command from the root of the project will help you find out.